# Read Only Google+ Share

Tags: google-plus

I am able to use Google+ to sign in to our site and able to populate a share dialog using Google's documentation.  For the project I am working on, I am being told that the legal department wants all the shares to be uneditable.  Does anyone have any ideas or resources they could point me to for how to accomplish this?

I know that the guidelines for all the social sites say this is frowned upon.  We will be showing them a preview of what the share will look like before posting it to their wall and the share will ALWAYS be user initiated.  There is no attempt at deception on our end.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google+ the user always has full control over sharing, this includes decisions on whether or not they want to disable comments on posts that they share. You cannot programmatically disable this ability.

It would be interesting to know your use case more, if you can, [report the issue and use case in detail](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry?template=Bug%20-%20Plugins) on the Google+ issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks Brett.  I suspected as much.  I will fill out the form.  It is a promotion (where the user has a chance to win something).  The lawyers say that our exposure comes from the possibility of the user misrepresenting the promotion in their comment.  We are going to push back a little on the lawyers and see if they are just being overly cautious.

Comment: You could try to craft the snippet that is rendered in the preview to include any details your lawyers find important to always be there. The snippet doesn't contain that many words though and it might defeat the purpose of your promotion if they insert a disclaimer there.